# Is this API response time normal?

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, latency, response-time

I am currently writing a RESTful API in Python (Flask) with uWSGI as the WSGI and NGINX as a reverse proxy.

The principle is simple:

1. The client POST request gets to the server with a small JSON object in its body
2. Through NGINX and then uWSGI, the request gets to my Python callable, which in turn calls a backend subprocess to handle the data processing
3. The backend data processing is all CPU-bound, no IO. For a single JSON object, **the raw data processing time when the server is idle is about 800 milliseconds**
4. The backend returns the raw data, which is then serialized in JSON and returned by the Python callable back to uWSGI then to NGINX and finally to the client

**The server has 8 single-core single-thread CPUs**.

NGINX is configured to have an automatic number of listeners (so it gets to 8 in this case), and pretty vanilla overall.

Here's the uWSGI configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
strict = true
need-app = true

master = true
processes = 8
single-interpreter = true
enable-threads = false
max-requests = 1000
max-worker-lifetime = 7200
reload-on-rss = 1024
worker-reload-mercy = 60
harakiri = 60

disable-logging = true
log-4xx = true
log-5xx = true
logto = uwsgi.log

vacuum = true
```

Running a load test with Jmeter -- 16 to 32 threads --, the throughput of this API seems to plateau at 7 to 8 requests / second, each individual request taking up to >4000ms latency (time to get a response at maximum load). During that test, all 8 CPUs of the server were used.

Increasing the number of uWSGI processes (either fixed or with cheaper and busyness configs) did seem to marginally harm the throughput and latency -- in any case, certainly didn't gain anything there.

Is this behaviour (especially the individual requests skyrocketing from 800ms to >4000ms latency) normal given my hardware and software configurations or am I missing something ?

Comment: With your setup a maximum throughput of about 8 requests per second is expected. The fact that you are close to this limit means that the additional latency is not due to additional CPU load. Did you look at the logs? You could look at the process IDs to see if python interpreter processes are spawned at a higher rate than you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your input @maarten. Regarding the increased latency during load, I made Python output app-level logs and indeed the latency originates outside the app level: the raw data processing time inside Python (thus independently of any external bottleneck like network) for each request does indeed increase by 200-300 ms, getting from 800ms to 1s. However, it never gets nowhere near the 4000ms full latency that I'm experiencing in total. Could that be due to a bottleneck at the uWSGI/NGINX level, or is it more likely to be caused by a physical network limitation?

Comment: I don't see how this would be caused by network limitations (assuming the client and server are on the same machine). I think the uWSGI and NGINX logs (in verbose mode) may provide more clues as to where the latency originates. One of the things to check would be at what rate new python processes are created. I'm sure the uWSGI log will inform you about new processes being created, but at the app level you can also log the PID of the current process (`os.getpid()`).

Comment: Thanks again, @maarten. I analyzed my app logs for the new PIDs spawning rate / sec: during maximal load times it went from 7 to 12. Seems pretty normal, right ? On the network side of things: the Jmeter server that runs the test is remote -- I thought this was pretty standard practice to avoid the testing processes and threads (emitting requests) interfering with your API serving those requests ; am I wrong ? My hypothesis now is that the end-to-end latency is due to requests (arriving way faster than 8/sec) waiting in a listen queue before getting served. Makes sense ? Thanks a lot, again.

Comment: I have no experience specifically with uWSGI but normally each process should last for much longer than a single request (you configured the upper limit using `max-requests` `max-worker-lifetime`), so if you are seeing 7/12 new PIDs per second that's way too much. You have a relatively high `reload-on-rss` setting already, but one explanation for the unintended reloading of workers at every request would be that this memory limit 1024MB is exceeded. When uWSGI logs at debug level it should provide clues.

Comment: Sorry for my inaccuracy: in my logs analysis, I was monitoring the rate of requests handling at app-level (basically, how many times per second my app, including every uWSGI worker, reports that it starts handling a new request [a given worker was done with its previous request]). This rate fluctuates between 7-12/s. For the actual new PIDs, I usually have 8 unique PIDs per hour -- 16 during the hours where uWSGI happens to reload its workers. Given this, does the hypothesis of latency due to listen queue hold ?

Comment: Regarding the resident memory limit per worker, it's very high indeed because each route of my API (in each uWSGI worker) loads a part of the OS filesystem in memory as an fs.memoryfs.MemoryFS() object (to avoid reading on persistent storage at every request). The workers are way below that limit during actual runtime (and their recycling helps keeping it that way) but I've set it generously to avoid any bad surprises in production.

Comment: In that case I think the server-side code works as expected, and indeed the latencies are probably due to the requests being buffered before they get processed. Assuming a FIFO policy for request queueing the latencies of the requests should increase from their initial values of ~1s for as long as the request firing rate is higher than the maximal processing capacity of the server (i.e. ~8 reqs/s). But latencies you see of course depend on how exactly Jmeter measures them (I have no experience with Jmeter).

Comment: In conclusion, if you can get Jmeter to send requests below 8 reqs/s and you still see this variance in latencies, then there's a problem, otherwise, I think there's no problem with your server-side setup.

Comment: I'm going to try the 8req/s test limit from the client side (thus preventing Jmeter from exceeding this limit) and have a look at the latencies then. In any case, I'm going to update this question if I catch something. Again, thank you so much for all this input !